# How to build a link based on a list of values?

Tags: python, hyperlink, increment

Let's say I have the following list in Python:

```
values = [sku1, sku2, sku3, sku4, sku5]
```

Based on list's length, I need to add each value from the list to a link.
For example if the list has 1 item, my link should be:

```
link = 'https://google.com/' + values[0]
```

If the list has 2 items, my link should be:

```
link = 'https://google.com' + values[0] + values[1]
```

..and so on.

I've tried doing this with:

```
if len(values) == 1:
      link = 'https://google.com/' + values[0]
if len(values) == 2:
      link = 'https://google.com' + values[0] + values[1]
```

But the input list can have any number of items so using so many ifs doesn't seem ok.
Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: Do you have a list containing lists inside of it? If so your given sample doesnt make a lot of sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
values = ["sku1", "sku2", "sku3", "sku4", "sku5"]
link = 'https://google.com/'
for value in values:
    link += value
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was trying lots of complicated ways when the solution was that simple.